# Call methods in sequence Angular 12

Tags: rxjs, angular12, subject-observer

I have three methods say method1, method2 and method3 which are implemented in three different services. Please note that these three methods use `httpClient` in turn. (i.e. they return Observable). method2 is called from different places. In one of the place, I want to call `method2` after `method1` and `method3` is completed.

How can I achieve this using `Rxjs` Subject or any other technique?

Answer (score 1):

Several operators allow you to execute observables in sequence.

The **concat** operator allows you to execute one observable and switch to the next after it completes.  This will produce three emissions:

```
concat(service1.method(), service3.method(), service2.method())
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
// outputs:
// service1 method result
// service3 method result
// service2 method result
```

If you want only a single emission when to occur after all complete, then you can use the **toArray** operator.

```
concat(service1.method(), service3.method(), service2.method())
  .pipe(toArray())
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
// output: [service1 method result, service3 method result, service2 method result]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have three methods, method1, method2 and method3 which are implemented in three different services.

```js
export class Service1 {
  // [...]
  method1(){
    // [...]
  }
}
export class Service2 {
  // [...]
  method2(){
    // [...]
  }
}
export class Service3 {
  // [...]
  method3(){
    // [...]
  }
}
```

> method2 is called from different places.

The first place:

```js
Service2.method2();
```

> In one of the place, I want to call method2 after method1 and method3 is completed.

```js
Service3.method3();
Service1.method1();
// called method 3 and method 1
Service2.method2();
```

OR

```js
Service1.method1();
Service3.method3();
// called method 1 and method 3
Service2.method2();
```

Comment: Hello Mrk Sef, sorry for confusion. All three methods return observable.